# How to install gem in Ruby / RoR script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a problem with this

```
rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.13)
irb(main):001:0> system "bundle install"
←[31mssh://git@sykav-sr-pr-004.domain.local:7999/kpr/kpr_exchange.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`←[0m
=> false
```

UPD

It's work for me:

```
Bundler.with_original_env { system('bundle install') }
```

result code for bundle install after add gem in gemfile:

```
def update_bundler
    crashed = false
    begin
        puts "START 'bundle install'"
        result = nil
        Bundler.with_original_env { result = system('bundle install') }
        raise if !result
        puts "DONE"
    rescue
        puts "WE HAVE PROBLEM IN bundler"
        crashed = true
        FileUtils.cp("Gemfile_backup", "Gemfile")
    end
    crashed
end
```

Comment: Why don't you run `bundle install` at your system's shell?

Comment: @user2422869 I need to install the gem inside the application, the successful implementation of track, make the notification and restart the server

Comment: It works for me using `system "sudo bundle install"`.

Answer (score 0):

**Console**

The problem you have is you're using the `Rails console` - you don't want to do that, you want to use your standard `system` `CMD`:

```
$ rails c
$ ... your stuff
$ exit
$ bundle install
```

[Rails is a gem too](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails) - meaning if you load the Rails console, it will be just like running an application on your system; you won't be able to call any OS-level commands.

`bundle install` is like a control panel function - it installs the required gems for your Rails app, meaning you need to run it at OS-level, not rails level

Comment: I need to install the gem inside the application, the successful implementation of track, make the notification and restart the server, how to do it is not at the level of rails?

Comment: But he's using [Kernel#system](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-system) method to run stuff at OS-level.

Comment: He's running the rails console & trying to load `bundle install`. This won't work (it's like trying to get an app in Windows to install a new program). You'll have to exit `rails c` and then use `bundle install`

Comment: Using `bundle install` *will* install for the application - but you must perform the command inside the app folder of your system shell not with `rails c`

Comment: @RichPeck so he should use `Dir.chdir("/path/to/application")` in order to get inside the app folder.
BTW, just installed gems with bundler within rails console.

Comment: @user2422869 if gem allready exist on machine - everything works, if gem has not been installed  - error. I add a record to a file when the application is running, and I want to install a new gem that is not on the machine.

Comment: If you're in the console, it means you're in the Rails app folder anyway - you should just exit the console & install from system shell

Comment: @RichPeck I need to implement the installation of gems in my application interface, on-demand option is set by action should gem 
I used rails console that would test the possibility

Comment: ohhh okay sorry. I thought it was another question about how to install gems from your system